# Visual Studio code Organize imports feature

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

On version 1.23 of visual studio code, the 'Organize imports' feature was added. This is a very helpful feature as it handles the imports itself, but I'd like to be able to configure it.

The functionalities I'd like to know if are available for this feature are:

- Is it possible to configure the order the imports are sorted? I'd like to configure external libraries (angular, rxjs) before my local imports
- Also, is it possible to add a line breaker between imports of different sources?
- On my project I have a max-line length configuration, but the import plugin doesn't seem to respect this. Shouldn't it?

I'm asking this questions because there is no configuration information available on VSCode page, only informing this is available.

Comment: Have you found a workaround to this? Currently tasked to order imports in the way you describe in a big project

Comment: Infortunatelly no. As the feature was not flexible, we decided to use it as the VSCode provided (changed our process instead of trying to customize the feature)

Comment: [vsc-organize-imports](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alfnielsen.vsc-organize-imports) worked for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, these more advanced options are not supported as of VS Code 1.24.

Max line length is tracked by [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22991)

External imports should generally come before internal imports. If you are using absolute paths, this may not be true, see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23577)

Our end goal with imports is to that you never have to manually manage your imports or even look at them, so more advanced sorting/styling is out of scope

Comment: more advantage sorting/styling would be nice, but it is not required. We will keep checking the max-length and the external before imports (we mix absolute/relative path) and the re-avaliate our standards.

Comment: The max line length issue is closed. What does that mean? Has it been implemented?

Comment: That issue isn't closed as of today, but it still hasn't been implemented.

Comment: Even if you don't look at the imports there is still an important reason to sort them according to a deterministic rule: to avoid unnecessary merge conflicts. Humans often follow the simplistic rule 'add a new import last', always ordering the imports makes conflicts less likely after such an addition.

Comment: The sorting is deterministic, it's just not configurable. That's left up to extensions

Answer (score 9):

On VSCode open ⇧⌘P or Ctrl+Shift+P then

"Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings..."

and add

```
"[typescript]": {
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true
}
```

}

Credits to this [source](https://eshlox.net/2019/12/02/vscode-automatically-organize-typescript-imports)

Comment: This doesn't answer any of the three questions the OP asked.

Answer (score 4):

There is an update to the `Organize Imports` function in vscode v1.68.  See [v1.68 Release Note: Group-aware Organize Imports](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_68.md#group-aware-organize-imports).

> Organize imports for JavaScript and TypeScript lets you quickly clean
> up your list of imports. When run, it both removes unused imports and
> also sorts the imports alphabetically.
>
> However some codebases like having some degree of manual control over
> how their imports are organized. Grouping external vs internal imports
> is one of the most common examples of this:

[Starting with this...]

```
// local code
import * as bbb from "./bbb";
import * as ccc from "./ccc";
import * as aaa from "./aaa";

// built-ins
import * as path from "path";
import * as child_process from "child_process"
import * as fs from "fs";
// some code...
```

[Organize Imports will now produce this:]

> With TypeScript 4.7 however, Organize Imports is now a group-aware.
> Running it on the above code looks a little bit more like what you’d
> expect:

```
// local code
import * as aaa from "./aaa";
import * as bbb from "./bbb";
import * as ccc from "./ccc";

// built-ins
import * as child_process from "child_process";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as path from "path";
// some code...
```

So you should be able to "group" your imports - separate by newline or comment and get them sorted only within each group.