# How to config VSCode's Organize Imports order?

Tags: node.js, import, visual-studio-code, eslint, tslint

I want to config Organize Imports's order.

Right now, it moves `node_modules` related import statement at the very top, and local `ts` file at very bottom:

Normal:

```
import myFunction from './myFunction';
import fs from 'fs';

console.log(fs)
console.log(myFunction)
```

After running Organize Imports command:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import myFunction from './myFunction';

console.log(fs)
console.log(myFunction)
```

What I want to do is reverse the order, I want `node_modules` to be very bottom, local imports to be very top.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: I am not familiar with the Organize Imports at all, but quick read-through of https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alfnielsen.vsc-organize-imports indicates that you will need to define your `groups` such that you have `relative` and `relativeDirect` higher in the array.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72553783/836330 for "group-aware Organize Imports" and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_68.md#group-aware-organize-imports.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The built-in "Organize Imports" functionality has no configuration, according to [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_organize-imports).

You can customize import ordering using a third-party extension, such as [`alfnielsen.vsc-organize-imports`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alfnielsen.vsc-organize-imports) or by using a separate linting tool like eslint or tslint.

In eslint (my recommendation, since tslint has been deprecated), you'll need to also use a plugin like [`eslint-plugin-import`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/order.md) to get the more-specific configuration you want. Then, instead of using the VSCode "Organize Imports" action, you'll use the "Fix All" action or a invoke a [quick fix](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_quick-fixes).

Here's a partial example `.eslint.js` config file.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "import",
  ],
  rules: {
    "import/order": [
      "error",
      {
        groups: [
          "index",
          "sibling",
          "parent",
          "internal",
          "external",
          "builtin"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: the order is opposite, it should be groups: ["builtin", "external", "internal", "parent", "sibling", "index", "object"]