# VSCode: how to config 'Organize imports' for Python (isort)

Tags: python, sorting, visual-studio-code, import, isort

Mirror question to:

- "[How to config VSCode's Organize Imports order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457410/how-to-config-vscodes-organize-imports-order)" which refers to a .js project.

I want to configure how VSCode is invoking [isort](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/custom_sections_and_ordering/), so I can customize when calling `Organize imports` in a .py file.

---

In particular, VSCode has started removing a blank line between two isort-sections, don't know why.

```py
from django...
from myproject... # removing blanck line between 2 sections
```

Comment: It seems that this might be helpful: https://medium.com/@cereblanco/setup-black-and-isort-in-vscode-514804590bf9 , you customize by altering the `"python.sortImports.args"`. Another alternative that I am using is the `pre-commit` with `isort`

Comment: When tried those, a pop-up appear:
"following deprecated CLI flags were used and ignored: -rc!"

Comment: I think the recursive option is deprecated since it is done automatically. https://github.com/PyCQA/isort/issues/1263

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In VS Code, the "Python" extension provides us with the following settings, which can merge specific imports from the same module into a single import statement, and organize the import statements in alphabetical order. (in "settings.json" file)

```
"python.sortImports.args": ["-rc", "--atomic"],
```

For using "Sort Imports" in VS Code, please refer to this document: [Sort Imports in VS Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_sort-imports)

Comment: do you know which flags to use for the "expected" order (one that doesn't lead to a `pylint-wrong-import` error)

Comment: @Manu  -I'm sorry I don't know about this, but you could create a new thread and describe this question in detail to get a better answer.

Answer (score 27):

You can make `isort` compatible with `black` and enjoy a formatted code upon saving your document. Here are two ways to achieve this:

1. You can configure `Black` and `Isort`’s settings on `pyproject.toml`.
   Inside your root’s project folder, create/update your `pyproject.toml` file:

```py
[tool.isort]
multi_line_output = 3
include_trailing_comma = true
force_grid_wrap = 0
line_length = 88
profile = "black"
```

2. Edit `settings.json` and configure `Black` and `Isort`.

```json
{
   "[python]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": true
       }
     },

   "python.formatting.provider": "black",
   "isort.args": ["--profile", "black"],
}
```

`source.organizeImports: true` runs Isort automatically upon saving your document.

Comment: Hey @xshapira do you need any extensions to make VSCode read that config from `pyproject.toml` file?

Comment: @jkulak You need `poetry` as your package manager and `pip install isort`.

Comment: Do you need any VSCode extensions for `isort` to read config from `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: @jkulak I think this used to work automatically in older versions of VSCode (or the Python extensions), but with the latest release it seems to have stopped working. I've opened an [issue here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20205).

Comment: Thx. I have a question about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330561/how-to-make-vscode-readisort-config-from-a-file

And also I am looking at that issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-isort/issues/71

Comment: Now we need to install [ms-python.isort](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.isort)

Comment: As of 2024 you need `"source.organizeImports": "always"` instead of `"source.organizeImports": true`.

Answer (score 20):

As of the end of 2022, the `python.sortImports` setting from the *vscode-python* will be removed. See [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/commit/792a965937eae65f4c1da2e3ede7d8f143aee88c).

VS Code wants us to use `isort.args` from the *[vscode-isort](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-isort)* instead. For example, the common configuration

```
   "python.sortImports.args": ["--profile", "black"],
```

should be replaced with

```
   "isort.args": ["--profile", "black"],
```

Otherwise you will see the

> "This setting will be removed soon. Use `isort.args` instead."

message.

Comment: If you also want to use `black` as a formatter, you will additionally need to install `ms-python.black-formatter` extension, then set your default formater for python to be `black`

Comment: I needed to add `"source.organizeImports": true`, otherwise it only checked `isort` upon save, it did not apply `isort`. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67059648/vscode-how-to-config-organize-imports-for-python-isort/72667901#72667901 )

Answer (score 4):

You can install [Isort extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.isort) to [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) as shown below. *I use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) on Windows 11:

[image]

Then, set the code below to `settings.json`. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-to-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file/76453531#76453531) explaning how to open `settings.json`:

```json
// "settings.json"

"[python]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true
    }
}
```

This below is my full `settings.json` with the code above:

```json
// "settings.json"

{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\kai\\anaconda3\\python.exe",
    "window.zoomLevel": 3,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
    "[python]": { // Here
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I needed. I had been trying to install isort into my virtual environment and hadn't realized there was an extension. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See my answer in
[How to find which isort is vscode exactly using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604348/how-to-find-which-isort-is-vscode-exactly-using/71579334#71579334)
where I describe the steps to see what is actually happening. You will see the command along with the arguments. The version of isort that is built in to the Microsoft Python plugin doesn't show as isort. Instead it is sortImports.py. It has the path so you can go look at the code for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In my case isort is not sorting the way I'd like to to be sorted.
Here's MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sea_bor_nnnn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import os
```

after saving the file I get the following output

```
import os
                            # why is it inserting an empty line here?
import numpy as np
import torch
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sea_bor_nnnn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
                               # here inserts only 1 blank line instead of 2
#actual code goes here
dfdf
dfdfd
ddf
```

My preferred format would be the following

```
import os
import torch
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sea_bor_nnnn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# actual code goes here
```

Notice how all imports are sorted according to length without empty lines in between and that actual code starts after 2 empty lines from the module imports.

Any ideas how to achieve that in vscode? Maybe using using `isort` in combination with `autopep8` or `flake8` instead of `black`